# auto keyword and storage class in C++ 11

Tags: c++11

Does the "auto" keyword in C++ have anything to do with storage class
For example:

```
void foo() {
  auto ptr = new int[9]
}
```

Does the pointer to int above have is automatic(stack), or dynamic(heap)?

Comment: `auto` is not used in C++11 as a storage-class specifier.

Comment: [What is the point of the 'auto' keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689733/what-is-the-point-of-the-auto-keyword)

Comment: The above code is equivalent to `int *ptr = new int[9];`,  But modern C++ doesn't like using (or abusing) `new` and `delete`, you should rethink your app in terms of `vector`, `array`, `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

Until `c++11`, `auto` was used to specify `automatic`storage duration. But since `c++11` its only meaning is that the type of the variable  is automatically deduced. It has nothing to do wiith the storage-class of the variable itself.

In your case `ptr` is a local variable (`int * ptr`) pointing to a location on the heap. You can always get the same effect by explicitely writing the types of the variables as in the following:

```
void foo() {
  int* ptr = new int[9];
}
```

Please take a look at [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) for more details and on how the deduction process works.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: missing semicolon 